# Is there an instant-updating function for texts or patterns as button.config() in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a modified program of the 'mines' game, and I hope it shows every step/click graphically. I use `time.sleep(0.5)` to make a pause. So, in general the main program is like:

> check_block():
>
> ```
> if mine == 0:
>     buttons[current].config(image = tile_clicked)
> elif mine == 1:
>     buttons[current].config(image = tile[1])
> ...
> ```
>
> while(1):
>
> ```
> time.sleep(0.5)
> check_block()
> get_next()
> if check_fail():
>      break
> ```

However, the buttons don't update every 0.5 second: they are all updated together when the `game(loop)` finishes.

I guess it's just like 'cout' in C++: if you don't flush they will get stacked. So, is there a method to get them updated step by step, or say, instantly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In all GUI systems you have to allow the message loop to run so that Windowing events occur promptly. So do not use a while loop like this. Instead, create a method that calls check_block() and get_next() and use `after` to call that function after a delay. At the end of that function, you use `after` again to call the same function again so that this function is called every 0.5 second forever. The after function queues a timer event and then lets the message queue be processed. Once your timer event fires, the callback function is run which allows you to do things and keep the UI responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call sleep in a GUI program. This is because the GUI must be "awake" at all times so that it can service events (including internal events that cause the screen to update). Instead, leverage the already-running eventloop by using the `after` method to put events on the queue at regular intervals.

In your case, you would replace the while loop with something like:

```
def do_check():
    check_block()
    if not check_fail():
        root.after(500, do_check)

# in your initialization code, start the loop by calling it directly:
do_check()
```

I don't know what your `get_next` function does, so I don't know if you need to call it periodically too. Probably not. I'm guessing it waits for the next button press, which you don't need to do with tkinter or most other GUI toolkits. Instead, you configure the button to call a function when clicked.

Regardless, the way to do the type of looping you want is to place events on the event queue at a regular interval.